# Docstring - quotes or semicolons?

Tags: comment, documentation, doc-strings

In the documentation I only see mention of using semicolons for comments and docstrings,
but in elisp-documents I regularly see functions documented in double-quotes, such as in `org.el`:

```lisp
(defun org-before-change-function (_beg _end)
  "Every change indicates that a table might need an update."
  (setq org-table-may-need-update t))
```

What should I use and where is the use of double-quotes for comments documented?

Comment: The question is unclear to me. I think it's about semicolons, but you mention double-quote chars and doc strings. Semicolons introduce comments in Emacs Lisp. Double-quote chars enclose strings. Doc strings are strings. Strings and comments are different animals.

Comment: "In the documentation I only see..." -- please provide links/references to those pieces of documentation, so that we can see specifically what you're reading.  You're conflating comments and docstrings, but maybe there's a flaw in the documentation, in which case it could be improved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is NOT a comment: that's the doc string of the function.

The doc string of the function is what you get when you ask for help on the function: `C-h f org-before-change-function` will show some information about the function *plus* its doc string:

```
org-before-change-function is a Lisp closure in ‘org.el’.

(org-before-change-function BEG END)

Every change indicates that a table might need an update.
```

OTOH, you have to open the file where the function is defined and search for it in order to see any comments that are attached.

Another way to look at it is that the doc string is external documentation, accessible easily in a standardized way; comments are internal documentation, meant more for the programmer who might want to understand or modify the function.

If you look at the doc string of `defun` with `C-h f defun`, you will see this:

```
defun is a Lisp macro in ‘byte-run.el’.

(defun NAME ARGLIST &optional DOCSTRING DECL &rest BODY)

...
```

The doc string is an argument to `defun`. `defun` defines a function, but it also squirrels away the doc string somewhere, so that when you ask for help on the function, it is retrieved and presented to you.